# Bind to external port-forwarded adress

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I have a computer let's call it `192.168.1.2` behind a NAT (`192.168.1.1`). The NAT port forwards the port `4444` to my computer's port `4444`. The external IP is `123.123.123.123`.

The computer can bind and listen for requests on `0.0.0.0:4444` and `192.168.1.2:4444` but I would like to bind directly to my external IP (e.g. `123.123.123.123:4444`)

Netcat seems unable to do it.

```
$> ncat -lv 123.123.123.123 4444
Ncat: Version 7.30 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: bind to 123.123.123.123:4444: Cannot assign requested address. QUITTING.
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Your application can only bind to an address which exists on the host where the application is run. It makes no sense to bind to your public address since any traffic coming to your host will have a destination address on your host. NAT will replace the WAN address with your hosts address on the IP packets.

Comment: @RonMaupin That makes sense now that I think about it... No idea what was going through my head.